# how to cast UITableViewCell Value properly to a string

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So my code looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
  let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
  performSegueWithIdentifier("TVtoVCSegue", sender: selectedCell)        
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "TVtoVCSegue" {
  let otherViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TTDetailCntr
  otherViewController.CurrentClass = String(sender!) as String
}
```

`otherViewController.CurrentClass` is connected to a label another viewController and its label says:

```
<UITableViewCell: 0x13f692230; frame = (0 132; 320 44); text = '10.d'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x13f692600>>
```

It should be "10.d" in this case. How can I achieve this?

I have looked up a lot of questions, if you find a duplicate then let me know or explain what am I doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access textLabel of a UITableViewCell "cell" like this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text
```

So you want to make the following change in your **prepareForSegue** function

```
if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, text = cell.textLabel?.text {
   otherViewController.CurrentClass = text
}
```

Comment: Although storing model data in table view cells is bad design. Better to fetch the data from the model object and pass that.

Comment: @DuncanC I couldn't agree more but I thought that may be out of the scope of his question.

Comment: @DuncanC I know, but once I'll get my project working I will start making my code design better.

Comment: "once I'll get my project working I will start making my code design better." That's not design, that's a recipe for spaghetti-code.

Comment: @KarlKivi if this answers your question and you don't need anymore help, don't forget to accept it as an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have the text that you install in the table view in an array somewhere. You should record the index of the selected cell into an instance variable in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, then use that to fetch the string for that entry in your table in your prepareForSegue method.

Something like this:

```
override func tableView(
  tableView: UITableView, 
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
  //You would need to create the instance var cellIndex
  self.cellIndex = indexPath.row
  let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
  performSegueWithIdentifier("TVtoVCSegue", sender: selectedCell)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
  sender: AnyObject?) 
{
  if segue.identifier == "TVtoVCSegue" 
  {
    //This code assumes that myModel is an array of structs. 
    //Change this code to fit your data model 
    //(should be the same code you use to set the text in the cell.)
    let stringToPass = myModel[self.cellIndex].stringValue
    let otherViewController = segue.destinationViewController 
      as! TTDetailCntr
    otherViewController.CurrentClass = stringToPass
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay this code is working, but the viewController loads twice? I read that I can't implement both didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue functions that I have to implement only prepareForSegue and put all the code there. Should I ask another question or can you help me? @Duncan